# I heard Santa's little helper insult me!

Tags: cryptic-clues

A seasonal cryptic-crossword-style clue:

"I heard Santa's little helper insult me! (7)"

Comment: Where's the definition? Also, generally uncommon phrases are clued word-by-word rather than as a whole.

Comment: @Deusovi just one word (your second answer).

Comment: I meant in the clue. Cryptic clues have a definition *and* wordplay.

Comment: Yeah, 'santa's little helper' is doing double service. Rules differ anyway. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptic_crossword#British_and_North_American_differences

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hm, is it

> RUDE ELF / RUDOLPH?

It wouldn't *quite* fit cryptic crossword style, and I'm not sure where the definition would be, but at least I sort of have the

> homophone from "I heard"

Comment: The clue states it is one word, so it's not your first answer.  It's most likely your second answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think an answer is,

> Tony Cox

Reason:

> It's a 7 character.
>  He's an actor, who played a role of `Little helper` in bad santa movie released in 2003.
>  Check this: https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Bad_Santa

Comment: It has two words composed of 8 letters.  How does that fit the "(7)" clue?

Comment: Interesting attempt, but no, not what I was going for.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the answer may be

> SELFISH

My rationale is the following:

> I heard = Anagram
>  Santa's little helper = ELF
>  insult = HISS
>  me! = Definition (including the exclamation point)

Comment: Nice alternative answer!

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

> slander

Reason:

> *Slander* means "a malicious, false, and defamatory statement or report." The word somewhat sounds like "S(anta's) l(ittle) helper"

Comment: Nice try, but not the intended answer.